# Group by and keep the entire row which has max value across different columns

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a df that looks like:

```
# Groups:   telefono1 [360]
   nombre telefono1 telefono2 ads_ao ads_am ads_mas ads_ma total_price_ao total_price_am total_price_mas~ total_price_ma
   <chr>  <chr>     <lgl>     <chr>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>            <chr>         
 1 CRIST~ 60***0400 NA        0           0 0          0      0                           0 0                0             
 2 CRIST~ 60***0400 NA        0          61 0          0      0                           0 0                0             
 3 CRIST~ 60***0400 NA        0           0 0          0      0                           0 0                0             
 4 DIEGO~ 60***0844 NA        0           0 0          0      0                           0 0                0             
 5 Diego  60***0844 FALSE     0           0 0          2      0                           0 0                22500         
 6 TALLE~ 60***4848 NA        2           0 0          0      59000                       0 0                0             
 7 TALLE~ 60***4848 NA        0         311 0          0      0                           0 0                0             
 8 Rub?n  60***4848 FALSE     0           0 0          2      0                           0 0                59000
```

I need to group by telefono1 and then keep the entire row which value across columns "ads_ao, ads,am, ads_mas and ads_ma" was the maximum value.

In the example, the right solution were rows #2, #5 and #7 because they are the ones, groupping by telefono1, that have the maximum value across mentioned columns.

I tried it with dplyr

```
  group_by(telefono1) %>%
  mutate(max_value = max(ads_ao, ads_am, ads_mas, ads_ma)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But with this method I get a new variable with max value in all rows and then I can't use a top_n() to get the row with the max value because all are equal.

Please, anyone know any solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is to `filter` the row with the max values `across` columns that starts with 'ads', create the 'max_value' column(it is just to show the steps more clearly) with `pmax` (`vectorized` option to get the `max` per row), then grouped by 'telefono1', use `slice_max` on the 'max_value' column to return only that row where the 'max_value' is max, `ungroup` and remove the 'max_value' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(max_value = invoke(pmax, select(., starts_with('ads')))) %>%
   group_by(telefono1) %>%
   slice_max(max_value) %>%
   # or use 
   # slice(which.max(max_value)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-max_value)  
# A tibble: 3 x 11
#  nombre telefono1 telefono2 ads_ao ads_am ads_mas ads_ma total_price_ao total_price_am total_price_mas. total_price_ma
#  <chr>      <int> <lgl>      <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>          <int>          <int>            <int>          <int>
#1 CRIST~ 600040400 NA             0     61       0      0              0              0                0              0
#2 Diego  600530844 FALSE          0      0       0      2              0              0                0          22500
#3 TALLE~ 600674848 NA             0    311       0      0              0              0                0              0
```

If the dataset is already grouped, `ungroup` it first before creating the `max_value` column

```
df1 %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(max_value = invoke(pmax, select(., starts_with('ads')))) %>%   
   group_by(telefono1) %>%
   slice(which.max(max_value))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
mx <- do.call(pmax, df1[startsWith(names(df1), 'ads')])
subset(df1, mx == ave(mx, telefono1, FUN  = max))
#  nombre telefono1 telefono2 ads_ao ads_am ads_mas ads_ma total_price_ao total_price_am total_price_mas. total_price_ma
#2 CRIST~ 600040400        NA      0     61       0      0              0              0                0              0
#5  Diego 600530844     FALSE      0      0       0      2              0              0                0          22500
#7 TALLE~ 600674848        NA      0    311       0      0              0              0                0              0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(nombre = c("CRIST~", "CRIST~", "CRIST~", "DIEGO~", 
"Diego", "TALLE~", "TALLE~", "Rub?n"), telefono1 = c(600040400L, 
600040400L, 600040400L, 600530844L, 600530844L, 600674848L, 600674848L, 
600674848L), telefono2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE
), ads_ao = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), ads_am = c(0L, 
61L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 311L, 0L), ads_mas = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), ads_ma = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L), total_price_ao = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 59000L, 0L, 0L), total_price_am = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), total_price_mas. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), total_price_ma = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22500L, 0L, 0L, 
59000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: I can't use slice_max function and I get this error with your base R solution: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: @kikusanchez i have added an option `slice` which is commented below, please use that while commenting the `slice_max` line

Comment: I have problems too:
Adding missing grouping variables: `telefono1`
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `max_value`.
x Input `max_value` can't be recycled to size 3.
i Input `max_value` is `invoke(pmax, select(., starts_with("ads")))`.
i Input `max_value` must be size 3 or 1, not 889.
i The error occurred in group 1: telefono1 = "600040400".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @kikusanchez is this based on the same data.  Can you test it on the data in my post

Comment: It works with yours but not with mine. Maybe because yours is a list and mine is a dataframe?

Comment: @kikusanchez it is a data.frame as yours.  Can you show the `dput` of a small example that gives the error i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))`.  Then, it can be tested

Comment: Finally it works, but running it in two different lines: 

mx <- do.call(pmax, dup[startsWith(names(dup), 'ads')])

mx <- subset(dup, mx == ave(mx, telefono1, FUN  = max))

Thanks!

Comment: @kikusanchez i think i understand why you have an issue.  Your dataset is already grouped.  Can you try `df1 %>% ungroup %>% mutate(max_value = invoke(pmax, select(., starts_with('ads')))) %>%
   group_by(telefono1) %>% slice(which.max(max_value))`

Comment: YES! That's it! Now it works 100%!! It was that! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(telefono1) %>%
 slice_max(pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("ads")), max), 1)

  nombre telefono1 telefono2 ads_ao ads_am ads_mas ads_ma total_price_ao total_price_am total_price_mas. total_price_ma
  <chr>      <int> <lgl>      <int>  <int>   <int>  <int>          <int>          <int>            <int>          <int>
1 CRIST~ 600040400 NA             0     61       0      0              0              0                0              0
2 Diego  600530844 FALSE          0      0       0      2              0              0                0          22500
3 TALLE~ 600674848 NA             0    311       0      0              0              0                0              0
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in slice_max(., pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("ads")), max), 1) : 
  could not find function "slice_max"

Comment: It should be available from version 1.0.0, do you have that?

Comment: Yes, dplyr version 1.0.2 and...
> df1 %>%
+   group_by(telefono1) %>%
+   slice_max(pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("ads")), max), 1)
Error: `...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>

Comment: No, it is working fine for me. Perhaps initiate a clean `R` session.

Comment: It works but as akrun has suggested first I had to ungroup my df because it was already grouped. df %>% ungroup %>% mutate(max_value = invoke(pmax, select(., starts_with('ads')))) %>%    group_by(telefono1) %>%
 slice_max(pmap_dbl(across(starts_with("ads")), max), 1)